# android emulator, get the widgets on home screen

Tags: android, android-widget, homescreen

i am currently working on getting the list of widgets that are present on home screen, i want to write a code that can create a list of all the widgets **present on home screen**.
googled it but no luck!
any help is appreciated!
thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are dozens, perhaps hundreds, of home screen implementations. Perhaps one will have an API that will let you accomplish this, but there is no standard API for this.